# Why is the charge of this surface specified?

Tags: electricity

I am working on a problem where I have a conducting disk and a point charge above it and I must describe the charge density throughout the disc. What confuses me is that my result seems to specify what the net charge of the disc is. How is this possible? To me it seems that the discs net charge is an independent variable that is not specified in the problem and cannot change

Comment: It would help if you post more of your work. Of course you should be able to determine a net charge of the disk when you integrate over the charge distribution.

Comment: But isnt the net charge of the disc a fixed variable? For example increasing the point charge implies a higher net charge of the disc.

Comment: If the conductor is not grounded then yes, that doesn't make sense. No one here can help you further though unless you show more of your work.